# Row count in filtered DataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How can I get the number of results after filtering in a paged DataTable in PrimeFaces?

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="x" value="#{dbBean.xSorted}" paginator="true" rows="20">
    <p:column sortBy="#{x.id}" filterBy="#{x.id}" filterMatchMode="exact">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="ID" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{x.id}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The table has ~20 columns which can be sorted and filtered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `currentPageReportTemplate` attribute of the `p:dataTable` component:

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="x" 
       value="#{dbBean.xSorted}" paginator="true" rows="20"
       currentPageReportTemplate="(Displaying {startRecord} - {endRecord} of 
       {totalRecords}, Page: {currentPage}/{totalPages})">
 ...
</p:dataTable>
```

The text outside curly brackets can be changed.